# Bundle Product: Default Selection Price

Tags: price, indexing, ee-1.13, bundled-product

I have a bundle product set-up which has a default selection in the admin section. The bundle product uses the dynamic pricing option and all the prices and tier prices are on the option's products.

How can I get the price information for the bundle product with this default selection?

On further investigation it appears that the index is not finding any bundle products to index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the product with with the way that the products had been imported.

After fixing the import to set the price type on the bundle product to be dynamic then the index table was filled.

Comment: I tested, and it seems once you create a bundled product, you cannot change the pricing type. If it's fixed, it stays fixed. If it's dynamic, it stays dynamic. It would appear one would have to re-create another bundled product with dynamic or fixed pricing (depending on which one is not present).

Answer (score 1):

You can get bundle product max and min price using this model function

```
Mage::getModel('bundle/product_price')->getTotalPrices($_product,'max',1);
```

Where 1 inidcate whether you want bundle product price with include tax.

Comment: that is returning 0 for my product :( do I need to do anything to set the default selections?

Comment: On which page are you checking?

Comment: Product details page

Comment: I am using this on product detail page and my bundle product have multiselect option to choose.

Comment: It appears to be an issue with indexing, see my update